# How to obtain displacement from strain tensor?

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I know the relation

$$
\varepsilon =\frac{(\nabla + \nabla^T)}{2} u
$$

to obtain strain tensor $ \varepsilon$ from vector field of displacements $u$.

But, is it possible to obtain displacements from strain tensor and how?

Comment: If $y = Ax$ then $x = A^{-1}y$, no?

Comment: @JonCuster In a way yes, but I will need more "idiot proof" answer here as I am not a mathematical genius. Or better said, how can I figure out what $A$ is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is it possible?

Yes, it is possible in some cases. The condition for these are called *compatibility conditions*, and can be written as

$$\nabla \times \nabla \times \varepsilon= 0\, ,$$

or, in index notation,

$$\frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon_{ij}}{\partial x_k \partial x_l}
+ \frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon_{kl}}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
- \frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon_{il}}{\partial x_j \partial x_l}
- \frac{\partial^2 \varepsilon_{jl}}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}  = 0\, .$$

If these relationships hold you can obtain a **compatible** displacement field from your strain field¹.

¹ This is true for simply connected bodies, it is a bit more complicated otherwise.

#### How?

The simplest approach is to integrate the axial components and form differential equations from the shear components. For example, in 2D you have the following

\begin{align}
&u = \int \varepsilon_{xx} dx + f_2(y)\, ,\\
&v = \int \varepsilon_{yy} dx + f_1(x)\, .\\
\end{align}

Then,

$$2\varepsilon_{xy} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\, ,$$

and you take the derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ to get differential equations for $f_1$ and $f_2$. You still need boundary conditions to find the constants that come from the differential equations for $f_1$ and $f_2$. In 3D this is a bit more cumbersome, but not conceptually different.

Alternatively, you could find the rotation tensor $\omega$ and integrate the system directly since the sum of the two is the complete (linearized) gradient. In 2D finding the rotation tensor is equivalent to solve the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Ok this is the condition. So if the above condition is satisfied, the displacement can be obtained. My question is how?

Comment: I don't think the answer can be *unique*: rigid body motions give zero strain, but non-zero displacements.

Comment: @mikestone Yes, it is not *unique* you still need to satisfy boundary conditions to find the constants of integration.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311625/strain-rate-tensor-derivation/311738#311738).  There it is explained how the strain tensor $\epsilon$ is a symmetric matrix that along with an antisymmetric matrix of rotation angles makes up all 3x3 matrix transformations M.

Let's just talk about the matrices $M$ that are very close to the identity matrix, where all elements in the matrix $\Theta$ are <<1. All these elements are in radians.
$$ 
M=I+\Theta
$$
$$
\Theta = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 & \theta^{12} &-\theta^{13} \\
-\theta^{12} &           0 & \theta^{23} \\ 
 \theta^{13} &-\theta^{23} &           0  \\
\end{bmatrix}_{Asymmetric}
\
+ \begin{bmatrix} 
\epsilon^{11} & \epsilon^{12} & \epsilon^{13} \\
\epsilon^{12} & \epsilon^{22} & \epsilon^{23} \\
\epsilon^{13} & \epsilon^{23} & \epsilon^{33} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}_{Symmetric}
$$

Now apply M to a vector x to get X.  We have moved a small piece of a body from x to X.
$$
X^i=M^{ij}x^j=(\delta^{ij}+\Theta^{ij})x^j
$$
$$
u^i=(X^i-x^i)=\Theta^{ij} x^j
$$
Where u is the “displacement” of the point.   If we only do strains ($\Theta^{ij}=\epsilon^{ij} $), then
$$
u^i=\epsilon^{ij} x^j
$$
So, you can obtain the displacements $u$ from the strains $\epsilon$ if you know the vector $x$ being strained. I think the matrix $A=\epsilon^{ij}$ is what Jon Custer refers to in his comment to your question. If you know $\epsilon$ and $u$, the vector $x$ is
$$
x=A^{-1}u
$$